# Accessing multiple roles from database in spring boot security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, roles

I have 3 tables USERS(has user details),ROLES(has roles' details),USER_ROLES(maps user_id to role_id). I want to retrieve roles of a user. When i imported them as entities ,my code looks like this:

### User.java

```
package com.eaiesb.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the USERS database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private String userId;

    private String column1;

    private String column2;

    private String emailid;

    private String gender;

    private String name;

    private String password;

    private BigDecimal sno;

    private String status;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Role
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="USER_ROLES"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")
            }
        )
    private List<Role> roles;

    public User() {
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getColumn1() {
        return this.column1;
    }

    public void setColumn1(String column1) {
        this.column1 = column1;
    }

    public String getColumn2() {
        return this.column2;
    }

    public void setColumn2(String column2) {
        this.column2 = column2;
    }

    public String getEmailid() {
        return this.emailid;
    }

    public void setEmailid(String emailid) {
        this.emailid = emailid;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSno() {
        return this.sno;
    }

    public void setSno(BigDecimal sno) {
        this.sno = sno;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return this.roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

"Role.java" looks similar too. I want to add roles of the user in getAuthoritites() of UserDetails, but am not able to, because it demands String but i can get roles only as List type.

Tried casting to String with regular Java methods, but was of no help.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `getAuthorities(User)` should looks like:

```
private List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Role role : user.getRoles() {
        result.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    }
    return result;
}
```